# SQL - Select Records after current date/time

Tags: sql, time, where-clause

So I have a table set out below

```
Date       Time        Field3        Field4 - etc.
--------------------------------------------------
05/07/11   17:45       blah          blah
05/07/11   19:45       blah          blah
08/07/11   17:30
08/07/11   19:00
09/07/11   19:00
```

etc.

I currently have one rule in under my WHERE Statement so that is shows all days between today (so it would be 05/07/11 until the same date 3 years later 05/07/14).

I would also like to add another rule under the WHERE Statement so that it only shows times (when the current date is equal to the date in the table) two hours before the current time.

So on the 05/07/11 at 19:00 it should show:

```
Date       Time        Field3        Field4 - etc.
--------------------------------------------------
05/07/11   17:45       blah          blah
05/07/11   19:45       blah          blah
08/07/11   17:30
08/07/11   19:00
09/07/11   19:00
```

at 21:46 on the same day, it should now show:

```
Date       Time        Field3        Field4 - etc.
--------------------------------------------------
08/07/11   17:30
08/07/11   19:00
09/07/11   19:00
```

How would I do this in my SQL? I'm thinking it'd have to be an if then or case when then statement, but i havent been able to work it out?

ALSO Date is generated within VB.Net, so would the time. Current sql (and working) code is:

```
SELECT m.MatchID Manage, m.Date, m.Time, t.TeamCode "Home", b.TeamCode "Away", 
g.GroundName "Ground", ( SUBSTRING(u.GivenName,1,1) + '. ' + RTRIM(u.Surname) ) AS Referee, 
( SUBSTRING(v.GivenName,1,1) + '. ' + RTRIM(v.Surname) ) AS "Assistant 1", 
( SUBSTRING(w.GivenName,1,1) + '. ' + RTRIM(w.Surname) ) AS "Assistant 2", 
a.FOfficialID, a.AssessorID, a.RefereeAID, a.AReferee1AID, a.AReferee2AID, 
a.FOfficialAID, a.AssessorAID, 'Details' "Details", t.AgeGroupID, r.WetWeatherID 

FROM Match m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Appointment a ON m.MatchID=a.MatchID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN WetWeather r ON r.MatchID=m.MatchID 
INNER JOIN Team t ON m.HomeTeamID=t.TeamID 
INNER JOIN Team b ON m.AwayTeamID=b.TeamID 
INNER JOIN Ground g ON g.GroundID=m.GroundID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users u ON u.UserID=a.RefereeID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users v on v.UserID=a.AReferee1ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users w on w.UserID=a.AReferee2ID 

WHERE (m.Date BETWEEN '05-Jul-2011' AND '05-Jul-2014')
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: And what data-types are the DATE and TIME columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding columns Date and Time and the compare against the interval -2 hours +3 years.

```
select *
from YourTable
where Date+cast(Time as datetime) between dateadd(hour, -2, getdate()) and dateadd(year, 3, getdate())
```

Not sure if any index on Date can be used in the above query. If you have performance issues you could try this instead. It might do a better job using a Date index.

```
select *
from YourTable
where Date between cast(getdate() as date) and dateadd(year, 3, getdate()) and
      Date+cast(Time as datetime) > dateadd(hour, -2, getdate())
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use the databases time and date fields, you may simple compare to current date/time

```
…
WHERE `Date` > NOW()
AND `Time` > NOW()
```

Comment: that only brings back only dates greater than today with only times later than 10:10, so from the tables above, itd bring back nothing

Comment: Well, you use `WHERE (m.Date BETWEEN '05-Jul-2011' AND '05-Jul-2014')` in your working example, why don't you just expand it to the time, passing the computed (via VB) date and time into to the WHERE-clause. So what was the question, if you have the solution in your working example?

Comment: okay, i understand what your trying to tell me, but i already tried that:
'WHERE (m.Date BETWEEN '05-Jul-2011' AND '05-Jul-2014') AND m.Time >= '20:36''
only brings back dates that are greater than 5th July and have a time later than 20:36, i want it to show all times from the 6th july onwards, kind of like a calendar, all times after the current time - 2hours

Comment: Mh, if your SQL-server has a Datetime-type you may stick to that.
The following works for me (using MySQL): `SELECT * FROM user_attribute WHERE registered_since BETWEEN '2010-12-13 17:54:57' AND '2011-02-09 08:36:11'` (You still need to compute the to dates.)
You may also create a view, using datetime-fields, if you need to leave the table-structure as is.

Comment: That would be Date > Now() OR (Date = Now() AND Time>Now()) I assume?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it by joining to a sub query.  Something like:

```
     select ...
     from Match as m
     inner join
        (select mSub.MatchID, 
        case when Date+cast(Time as datetime) between dateadd(hour,-2,getdate()) 
             and getdate() then 1 else 0 end as Show
        from Match as mSub
        where Date between 
           cast(getdate() as date)
           and cast(dateadd(year,3,getdate()) as date)
         ) as Control
      on Control.MatchID=m.MatchID
```

So the sub query gives you your Show column that you can use in your CASE statement and it does your filtering.